# Special characters in WCF web API URLs

Tags: special-characters, restful-url

I have a web service which uses the WCF web api to create RESTful service. This serivce expects many different values in the url path seperated with a comma. This method works perfectly for simple data e.g. someones name or a numeric value. However I have a field on the client side (a java based BlackBerry app) which allows a user to freely type data which includes characters such as . or / which messes up my whole url.

Even when I replace the characters with their hex values e.g. a / to %2F the problem persists.

Does anyone know a means to either represent these characters in a URL which will be ignored when looking for the address or better yet a means to tell the URL the following characters are to be ignored perhaps in the way quotation marks would work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use encode url function. URL Encoding is the process of converting string into valid URL format. Valid URL format means that the URL contains only what is termed `alpha | digit | safe | extra | escape` characters.